# libgcov profiling error - overwriting an existing profile data with a different timestamp

Tags: c++, c, gcov, gcovr

My issue is different than [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68136230/gcda-file-coverage-info-not-getting-updated-when-two-executables-run-for-same-s): the problem there was that he was compiling the same file twice.

I am only compiling each file once.

```
g++ -c "file_1.c" -o file_1.o  -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage  
g++ -c "file_2.c" -o file_2.o  -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
g++ -c "file_3.c" -o file_3.o
g++ file_1.o file_2.o file_3.o -lgcov --coverage
```

Then when I run it, I get the error:

```
./a.exe
libgcov profiling error:file_1.gcda:overwriting an existing profile data with a different timestamp
libgcov profiling error:file_2.gcda:overwriting an existing profile data with a different timestamp
...
```

**QUESTION**
Why is there an error given that I only compile each instrumented file once unlike the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68136230/gcda-file-coverage-info-not-getting-updated-when-two-executables-run-for-same-s)?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Which version of GCC are you using? Could you provide a minimal example for those three files? Are three files necessary, or can it be reduced further?

Comment: @amon problem was solved once I removed the artifacts from previous compilation.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when compiling criterion in C, and found this [website](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71586011/) which explained what the origin of the error was and how to solve it.
Turns out the problem was that Criterion uses file names to create its object files, and I had a file named src/str.c and a file named tests/str.c, which tested the src/str.c file.

Because those two files had the same name, even tough they were not in the same directory, Criterion encountered problems when creating object files.

You can **fix this issue** by **changing the files' name**.
For example, I changed the tests/str.c into a tests/test_str.c.

If this doesn't work, you can also try removing the .gcno and .gcda files before executing the program.

Comment: You've linked to a dubious scraper site that just copies content from stack overflow. The original link is https://stackoverflow.com/a/71586011/4657412

Comment: @DavidW I just periodically search for links to that site (and others) and remove them from SO. Fortunately, these websites often use url suffixes that are easily searchable and match SO posts.